# pandas - aggregating on contents of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
       Lane PropA PropB PropC
Sample                       
NameA    R1  PASS  FAIL  WARN
NameB    R2  FAIL  FAIL  PASS
NameC    R1  WARN  PASS  PASS
NameD    R2  PASS  PASS  WARN
```

I have as a goal to produce a bar plot that for each Prop shows how many of the Samples have PASS, WARN or FAIL as a value. Thus I need to get out a dataframe where the contents are like this instead:

```
       PASS   WARN    FAIL
Prop
PropA  3       2       1
PropB  2       5       3
PropC  2       5       1
```

How to I get from the dataframe above to the one below?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter only necessary columns by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) or [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and then count with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and then if necessary replace `NaN`s to `0` by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df1 = df.drop('Lane', 1).apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).T.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.filter(like='Prop').apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).T.fillna(0).astype(int)

print (df1)
       FAIL  PASS  WARN
PropA     1     2     1
PropB     2     2     0
PropC     0     2     2
```

And last:

```
df1.plot.bar()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will work.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['PASS', 'WARN', 'FAIL'])

for col in df.columns[1:]:
    new_df = new_df.append(pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(col)[col].count()).transpose())
```